# Changing java.policy file for applet

Tags: java, security

I had exception in Applet as follow.

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (“java.security.SecurityPermission” “authProvider.SunMSCAPI”)

SOT : [java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.security.SecurityPermission" "authProvider.SunMSCAPI")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401951/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-security-securityperm/19407596?noredirect=1#comment28788356_19407596)

This is solved by changing `java.policy` file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\security`. I added new permission lines in it. As follow

```
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.home", "read";
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.dir", "read";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";
```

I did it manually but our application running all around the world. And I can't go to each user to change the `java.policy` file. And also some user don't have admin access to change that file. So is there any way we can set runtime parameter(s) or something else...